# Why does this javascript loop return infinitely?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, infinite

Can someone please explain to me why the following code returns an infinite loop rather than redefining `foo`?

```
var foo = 2;

while (foo = 2) {
   foo = 3;
}

console.log('foo is ' + foo);
```

Of course, the first time through the loop is going to run because `foo` indeed equals `2`. However, I don't understand why to keeps running; after the first time through `foo` should now be set to 3, the parameter should return false, and `console.log('foo is ' + foo);` should print `foo is 3`.

Clearly I am missing something here.

Comment: what is that even supposed to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the value 2 to `foo` instead of comparing it in the condition here:

`while (foo = 2)`

Change it to:

`while (foo == 2)`

Answer (score 2):

```
while (foo == 2) {
   foo = 3;
}
```

You are missing an equal sign (or two if you want an even stricter check)

```
while (foo === 2) {
   foo = 3;
}
```

Comment: No syntactically it is completely correct. It's a logical error.

Comment: JavaScript has a concept of "truthy" and "falsey", which means that you can use boolean logic on non-boolean values.  The value `2` is truthy, so `while (2)` is the same as `while (true)`.

Answer (score 0):

You may miss "while (foo == 2)" when open the loop,

if it again prints infinity let it know me..